# Java errors when loading an SQL query to test sampleclean

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hive

See the quickstart guide on installing sampleclean:
http://sampleclean.org/release.html

I have followed the steps provided in the quick start and have the correct versions:

```
$ javac -version  
javac 1.7.0_95  
$ scala  
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_95)
```

I wasn't able to install spark-1.2.2, so I got spark-1.6.1 instead.
After building spark, updating the hive conf file and running the scala commands, I get a java error:

```
~/sampleclean/spark-1.6.1$ ./bin/spark-shell --jars sampleclean-v0.1.jar 

scala> import sampleclean.api.SampleCleanContext
import sampleclean.api.SampleCleanContext

scala> val scc = new SampleCleanContext(sc)
scc: sampleclean.api.SampleCleanContext = sampleclean.api.SampleCleanContext@2d15f9f9

scala> scc.hql("CREATE TABLE restaurant(id String, entity String, name String, category String, city String) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'")
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sampleclean.api.SampleCleanContext.hql(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame;
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:31)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:44)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:46)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:48)
    at <init>(<console>:50)
    at .<init>(<console>:54)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I think I've followed all of the steps correctly. In addition, I can see the hql function defined in sampleclean/api/SampleCleanContext.scala.

Can somebody help to resolve this error.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think sampleClean works well with Spark apart from version 1.2.*. If you really need to use sampleClean, then you have to install spark 1.2 and start using it

Comment: @SamuelAlexander Thank you for your comments. I was able to get spark 1.2 running after much searching and jumping through some hoops (see https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/114). Now that I'm using spark1.2 I am able to complete the sampleclean tutorial.